# zurb-foundation gem not added to asset path in existing Rails 3.2 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, zurb-foundation, assets, sprockets

I have an existing Rails 3.2.14 application that I am trying to add zurb-foundation to.  I have added the zurb-foundation gem and run the installation generator.

My problem is that, whenever I try to load a page, I get this error:

```
couldn't find file 'foundation'
```

when Sprockets hits the

```
//= require foundation
```

line in application.js

The problem appears to be that the directory with the assets from the zurb-foundation gem are not being added to the load path.  In contrast, I have an application that I generated more recently, including zurb-foundation from the beginning, and @asset_paths.asset_environment.paths includes the following

```
"/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jquery-rails-3.0.4/vendor/assets/javascripts", 
"/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/coffee-rails-3.2.2/lib/assets/javascripts", 
"/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/zurb-foundation-4.3.0/scss", 
"/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/zurb-foundation-4.3.0/js"
```

which are not included in the asset load path in the app I am updating. Instead, I am getting (with p @asset_paths.asset_environment.paths in the better_errors diagnostic window)

```
"/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jquery-ui-rails-4.0.4/app/assets/images", 
"/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jquery-ui-rails-4.0.4/app/assets/javascripts", 
"/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jquery-ui-rails-4.0.4/app/assets/stylesheets", 
"/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jquery-rails-3.0.4/vendor/assets/javascripts", 
"/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/coffee-rails-3.2.2/lib/assets/javascripts"
```

interestingly, if I run the console in development mode and look at Rails.application.config.assets.path, it includes:

```
"/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jquery-ui-rails-4.0.4/app/assets/images", 
"/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jquery-ui-rails-4.0.4/app/assets/javascripts", 
"/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jquery-ui-rails-4.0.4/app/assets/stylesheets", 
"/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jquery-rails-3.0.4/vendor/assets/javascripts", 
"/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/coffee-rails-3.2.2/lib/assets/javascripts", 
"/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/zurb-foundation-4.3.1/scss", 
"/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/zurb-foundation-4.3.1/js"
```

and that DOES include the zurb-foundation asset paths.

I have included gem 'zurb-foundation' in the assets group, in the development group, and outside any group.  I am using zurb-foundation-4.3.1 in the new app.

My Gemfile assets group is:

```
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails'
  gem 'coffee-rails'
  gem 'uglifier'
  gem 'compass-rails'
  gem 'zurb-foundation'
end
```

This problem seems similar to [Sprockets::FileNotFound with ZURB Foundation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17969750/sprocketsfilenotfound-with-zurb-foundation), although Jurriaan did not mention the asset load path.

Any idea what I could be missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with a gem that was preventing foundation's entries being added to the load_path.  The gem involved was mongomapper-versioned.

By not loading that gem, the problem resolved.  By adding the gem back, the problem recurs.

That gem has not had any activity for two years.  I guess it's time to find something else.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried restarting the webserver?

Update:
You said it runs fine in development, Have you tried to rake assets:clean and rake assets:precompile?

Comment: I'm sure it is something simple, but that is not it.  I have re-run bundle install and restarting the server each time.  Thanks for trying!

Comment: I only asked because I ran into the same thing with that gem, it ended up being my fault for not restarting.

Comment: I didn't see your edit until just now, but sorry if I wasn't clear.  I was seeing this problem in development, and did not try any other environments.  rake assets:clean ran fine, but rake assets:precompile generated the same error.  However, it looks like the problem was caused by including the mongomapper-versioned gem.  Removing that gem from the Gemfile fixed the problem.